# Campaign Monitor Post with API Key

Tags: c#, api, campaign-monitor

I'm new to this so what I want to do is post an Ajax to campaign monitor to add a new subscriber to a my list. The issue here is that I've carried out the right procedures using [Campaign Monitors documentation](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/subscribers/#adding-a-subscriber). However I get a 401 error on the response regarding that the request was not authenticated. I'm just wondering how would I use the [API Key](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/getting-started/#authenticating-api-key) for this instance.

In JSON i am passing:

```
{ "Email Address": "test@test.com", "Name": "Test" }
```

Im passing this through by C#

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.createsend.com/api/v3.1/subscribers/LISTID.json", new StringContent(senderInfo, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
  }
```

Is there something I'm meant to be passing through here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems i was missing out the header for this response